# Test and Production server setup with git

Tags: git, repository

I am new to GIT. I have one production url and another as development url to which i want to push the new code.

**development**: http://development.myrepo.something

**production**: http://production.myrep.something

Now i usually work from different computers. I need a setup in which i can actually push all my work to the development url from different computers and when i get satisfied, i push the same thing in production url.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR**

1. Copied exactly same files on both the URLS. At this point both the URL's give me same result in broswer.
2. Executed git init in both the directories and made them git repos.
3. In the local git bash, I cloned from the production URL at some directory.
4. I then added a remote origin like this - git remote add production ......//server path here
5. Now i pulled from this repo like this - git pull production and it resulted like "UP TO DATE" which is what i wanted. Now pulling from both the branches give me the same message which is perfect.

So at thie point i thought, i can now work on local and then push to the development repo and when satisfied i can push again to the production repo.

But it doesn't work as whenever i push, it shows me the error because the repos aren't bare.

So what do i do now?

I am thinking to follow the branching approach from this [Link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

But the problem is that i want to see/test the work on the server in the development branch. With the approach mentioned in the above link, i can only see after the merge has been performed.

Please shed some light and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a *bare* repository on your server as a storage for production code, and setup a second non-bare repository somewhere near it which will *pull* from the bare one for testing. Dont' try to work against git.

The idea is that if you are using a repository to actually *write* code in it, then you shouldn't push to it.

---

So, first you create a repo for your code:

```
$ cd /path/to/dir/with/dev/repo
$ git init --bare
```

This is the repo you'll use as a central storage of your dev code, this one will be visible from the outside via `http` or whatever. You configure it as “dev” (or “origin”) remote in your working repos.

So, again, the repo you just configure is a push/pull-only repo, you don't actually do work in it: you write code in its clones and then push your changes. Even if you happen to work on the same machine, just clone:

```
$ cd /path/to/work/dir
$ git clone /path/to/dir/with/dev/repo
```

and when done push your changes back.

The same applies to your “production” repo. You set up a bare repository for production code *storage*, and then if you want to test it or deploy on the server, you just clone it to a non-bare repo on the same server—now you've got a repo for testing.

If you want your code to be *deployed* automatically when you push to a repo, there are a number of tutorials explaining how to achieve this with hoos (here is [one of them](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)).

Comment: can you please explain this process in a bit detail?

Comment: another question....i mistakenly initiated a bare repo on some directory. Can i undo this for that directory and do it in some other directory?

Comment: @beNerd Just remove those extra directories and files: `rm -rf HEAD config hooks objects branches description info refs`

Comment: I created a bare --init on a repo named directory. all works well. and on server through SSH, i do a pull from this repo into my web directory. Now when i open the url, it shows "Internal server error". I googled and it is due to some permissions issue. All files are set on 664 permission level. I am pushing into 'repo' directory using windows.

Comment: @beNerd I'm not sure, that's probably a different question. Open a new question, and, well, I think more deetails are needed.