# GIT Commit Structure

Tags: git, deployment

I'm very new to Git, but it is definitely needed in my development platform. I'm not sure if what I have in mind is the right way to go about it, and I'm not getting easy answers in a google search. So I'll just ask.

What I'd like to do is have 3 different servers, one for Development, one for testing the code, and one for Production. I'd like to be able to Develop the code on the one server, Commit it to the testing server, then once it's proved ok, commit it to the Production server.... all with Git.

Am I way off base here? Any recommendations for a better way forward?

If my concept is logical, how do I go about it? Could you please point me in the right direction, or tell me the commands necessary?

Thanks!!

Comment: You might find this post helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081647/test-and-production-server-setup-with-git

Comment: What you're asking about is *deployment*, which is a big topic, and Git is only a small part. You don't "commit to a server" but you can deploy certain branches to a server. Have a look into [The Twelve-Factor App](https://www.12factor.net/) and [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Git and servers aren't connected on that level. However, it enables using branching workflows that make it easy to work on a project while continuously adding bug fixes and new features without changing the production codebase. What is on the production server is basically an image of a specific branch. so let's say you have 3 branches in your project git repository:

1. main - this the production codebase
2. dev - this is a development to which you will merge your bug fixes and new features (and would eventually be merged to the 'main' branch)
3. my-personal-branch - a feature branch that you are working on that was created of the develop branch.

All of those are independent so you could deploy them individually to a testing server. a nice article about git workflow: https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf

Answer (score 0):

Git is a version control system and as so it will manage your versioning but you still have to do the deploy to your servers.

Git allow's you to create different **branches** for example is kind of normal to have the main working version of the program on the master branch, and then have a development branch where all the new features are testes together, kind of a staging environment:

[image]

This separation makes it easy to manage new weorking versions of the program and you can setup servers that only pull a specified branch, like a server that only has the developer branch running, and another that have the master branch running.

Checkout the documentation available about **Gitflow**.